# How can I select distinct thing with earliest date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to select top 7 station that got their first trip earlier than the other stations.
consider just the start station and start date, I want only the trip_id and station_id, and consider year 2015 only

[image: this is a table]

```
SELECT start_station_id AS station_id, trip_id
FROM Table
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(start_date), DISTINCT start_station_id
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY start_station_id
)
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) = 2015 
ORDER BY start_date
```

I did try some but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the join conditions. You can also remove the distinct on the inner query since you are grouping on `start_station_id`.

```
SELECT a.start_station_id AS station_id, a.trip_id
FROM Table a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(start_date) AS min_start_date, start_station_id
    FROM Table
    WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) = 2015
    GROUP BY start_station_id
    ORDER BY MIN(start_date)
    LIMIT 7
) b
ON a.start_station_id = b.start_station_id
AND a.start_date = b.min_start_date 
ORDER BY a.start_date
```

Comment: ```SELECT start_station_id AS station_id, trip_id
FROM bigquery-public-data.san_francisco_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(start_date), start_station_id
    FROM  bigquery-public-data.san_francisco_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips 
    GROUP BY start_station_id
)b
ON a.start_station_id = b.start_station_id
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) = 2015 
ORDER BY start_date
```

It still doesn't work
error shown :Column name start_station_id is ambiguous at [1:8]

Comment: I updated the question to use the table aliases right after I posted the answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer again to include the `LIMIT 7` requirement and move the where clause into the subquery.